# How to concatenate a string to a column in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, concatenation

I have the following data and would like to get the result with a text prefix:

Input dataframe:

```
sk            id       
2306220722    117738
```

Current code:

```
df.withColumn("Remarks", concat_ws("MCA", col("ID")))
```

Expected output:

```
sk           id      Remarks  
2306220722   117738  MCA 117738
```

I would like to prefix the `id` column with "MCA" and add the resulting string to the `Remarks` column.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use the `concat` command in combination with `lit`. `lit` will take a value and produce a column with only this value, it can be a string, double, etc.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Remarks", concat(lit("MCA "), col("id")))
```

Using the example dataframe in the question and running `df2.show()` gives

```
+----------+------+----------+
|        sk|    id|   Remarks|
+----------+------+----------+
|2306220722|117738|MCA 117738|
+----------+------+----------+
```

Comment: If you have null values in your column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310246/how-to-concatenate-to-a-null-column-in-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Dataset data1= data.withColumn("Name", functions.concat(functions.lit("SAR "),functions.col("Name")) ).show();

```
+---------+------------+---------+
|     Name|STRING_VALUE|NUM_VALUE|
+---------+------------+---------+
|SAR name2|      value2|        2|
|SAR name1|      value1|        1|
|SAR name1|      value1|        1|
|SAR name2|      value2|        2|
+---------+------------+---------+
```