# How to concatenate to a null column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a below dataframe and I wanted to update the rows dynamically with some values

```
input_frame.show()
+----------+----------+---------+
|student_id|name      |timestamp|
+----------+----------+---------+
|        s1|testuser  |       t1|
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|
|        s2|test123   |       t1|
|        s2|sample123 |       t2|
+----------+----------+---------+

input_frame = input_frame.withColumn('test', sf.lit(None))
input_frame.show()
+----------+----------+---------+----+
|student_id|      name|timestamp|test|
+----------+----------+---------+----+
|        s1|  testuser|       t1|null|
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|null|
|        s2|   test123|       t1|null|
|        s2| sample123|       t2|null|
+----------+----------+---------+----+

input_frame = input_frame.withColumn('test', sf.concat(sf.col('test'),sf.lit('test')))
input_frame.show()
+----------+----------+---------+----+
|student_id|      name|timestamp|test|
+----------+----------+---------+----+
|        s1|  testuser|       t1|null|
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|null|
|        s2|   test123|       t1|null|
|        s2| sample123|       t2|null|
+----------+----------+---------+----+
```

I want to update the 'test' column with some values and apply the filter with partial matches on the column. But concatenating to null column resulting in a null column again. How can we do this?

Comment: use `coalesce` to handle `null` values and `concat` on the obtained result.

Answer (score 19):

use `concat_ws`, like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([["1", "2"], ["2", None], ["3", "4"], ["4", "5"], [None, "6"]]).toDF("a", "b")

# This won't work
df = df.withColumn("concat", concat(df.a, df.b))

# This won't work
df = df.withColumn("concat + cast", concat(df.a.cast('string'), df.b.cast('string')))

# Do it like this
df = df.withColumn("concat_ws", concat_ws("", df.a, df.b))
df.show()
```

gives:

```
+----+----+------+-------------+---------+
|   a|   b|concat|concat + cast|concat_ws|
+----+----+------+-------------+---------+
|   1|   2|    12|           12|       12|
|   2|null|  null|         null|        2|
|   3|   4|    34|           34|       34|
|   4|   5|    45|           45|       45|
|null|   6|  null|         null|        6|
+----+----+------+-------------+---------+
```

Note specifically that casting a NULL column to string *doesn't* work as you wish, and will result in the entire row being NULL if any column is null.

There's no nice way of dealing with more complicated scenarios, but note that you can use a `when` statement in side a concat if you're willing to
suffer the verboseness of it, like this:

```
df.withColumn("concat_custom", concat(
  when(df.a.isNull(), lit('_')).otherwise(df.a), 
  when(df.b.isNull(), lit('_')).otherwise(df.b))
)
```

To get, eg:

```
+----+----+-------------+
|   a|   b|concat_custom|
+----+----+-------------+
|   1|   2|           12|
|   2|null|           2_|
|   3|   4|           34|
|   4|   5|           45|
|null|   6|           _6|
+----+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) function, which returns first of its arguments which is not null, and provide a literal in the second place, which will be used in case the column has a null value.

```
df = df.withColumn("concat", concat(coalesce(df.a, lit('')), coalesce(df.b, lit(''))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill null values with empty strings:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = spark.createDataFrame([('s1', 't1'), ('s2', 't2')], ['col1', 'col2'])
data = data.withColumn('test', f.lit(None).cast(StringType()))
display(data.na.fill('').withColumn('test2', f.concat('col1', 'col2', 'test')))
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: My idea of initializing with null values is to filter out the rows which are not updated. Basically concat operation will be performed with some criteria and such operations can be multiple. So I want to find the rows that didn't meet any of the criteria

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I got what you wanted to do but to resolve the issue with getting null values when you concat strings with null values, you only need to assign a data type to your all-null column: input_frame = input_frame.withColumn('test', sf.lit(None).cast(StringType()))